# SQL UPDATE : insert new word in the middle of a long string

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I have a string value like this :

```
DOMAIN1:word1,word2,word3#DOMAIN2:word4,word5#
```

And I want to insert a new word in the end of the DOMAIN1 like this :

```
DOMAIN1:word1,word2,word3,***newword***#DOMAIN2:word4,word5#
```

But I don’t know if it’s possible and if yes, can I do in Oracle SQL ?

Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 4):

One option uses `regexp_replace()`:

```
regexp_replace(mycol, '#DOMAIN2', ',newword#DOMAIN2')
```

Or, if you dont want to hardcode "DOMAIN2":

```
regexp_replace(mycol, '(DOMAIN1[^#]*)', '\1,newword')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8b10bb1585e595a197c5ae440eddb5a2)**:

```
with t as (select 'DOMAIN1:word1,word2,word3#DOMAIN2:word4,word5#' mycol from dual)
select mycol,
    regexp_replace(mycol, '#DOMAIN2', ',newword#DOMAIN2') mycol1,
    regexp_replace(mycol, '(DOMAIN1[^#]*)', '\1,newword') mycol2
from t
```

```
MYCOL                                          | MYCOL1                                                 | MYCOL2                                                
:--------------------------------------------- | :----------------------------------------------------- | :-----------------------------------------------------
DOMAIN1:word1,word2,word3#DOMAIN2:word4,word5# | DOMAIN1:word1,word2,word3,newword#DOMAIN2:word4,word5# | DOMAIN1:word1,word2,word3,newword#DOMAIN2:word4,word5#
```

Comment: Thumbs up to second version, but not the first one `:-)`